# Threadripper slows down render/loading process

Tags: rendering

I have the following problem. I work with 2 systems, an Intel i7 4770K and AMD threadripper 1950x. If i render my benchmark scene ( 30 gb ram) The intel workstation runs smooth and starts rendering after 3 minutes. The AMD threadripper needs 2 hours to load the scene.

When the threadripper starts rendering, it does everything quick and fast, but the scene buffering/ loading all assets,  takes a long time.

I work with the latest 2.79 blender release, no test build. Both systems have a clean windows 10 build and include all chipset drivers.

If i run the Blender official benchmark demo scenes, everything runs fine. Also the 16 gb production benchmark scene runs smooth. There is a difference between the intel and AMD system when loading, but it doesn't take more than 10 minutes extra for AMD and that's oke.

One more detail, the first 16 GB ram on the AMD system loads quick, but when it starts loading more ram than 16GB it slows down completely. I did a ram test in win 10 and everything was oke.

full specs AMD:

HTTA03 AMD Ryzen TR 1950X WOF   3400 TR4 BOX   | 
GTEG30 GiBy X399 AORUS Gaming 7  X399    |
HXLM63 CooMas MasterLiquid Pro 240     |
TN7V2L03 be quiet! Pure Power  10  700W ATX24    | 
GTX 970

If more details are needed, let me know

Comment: If i reduce the ammount of threads from 32 to 10, it speeds up the loading proces. Still taking 15 minutes, but way faster than using the deffault settings.

Comment: And how much RAM memory you have in both systems? Maybe you have only 16GB RAM and after AMD uses them it starts using virtual memory on HDD?

Comment: What's a threadripper, anyway?

Comment: Seaturtle. You have missed something huge. Threadripper is AMD's new CPU series which has two versions. One of which has 16 physical cores and 32 threads. I still don't understand though, why people get such immensely expensive and overpowered cpu's and think they are going to kill it in Blender. Blender is optimized for GPU rendering. If you bought your TR for Blender, you wasted over a thousand bucks. Well done.

Comment: Also, a GTX 970 and 16GB sysRAM on a 1950X system? You aren't giving your TR the chance to even run 100%. The graphics card will probably outrun your 1950X easily and 16GB is really limiting your TR CPU. It's really a waste in my opinion.